# Function definition diagram

Tags: diagrams, alignment

I'm wondering if it exists a canonical/natural/smooth/economical way of drawing such a diagram

[image]

for the definition of a function. The best I managed to do with tikz and align is very poor. I'm a beginner with Latex, hence I apologize in advance in case the question had a trivial answer.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE! If you want just this alignment, you only need an `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \mathscr{A}(B,C)\times\mathscr{A}(A,B) & \to & \mathscr{A}(A,C)\;,\\
  (g,f) & \mapsto & g\circ f\;,
 \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution based on `align*` and `eqparbox`. I added two variants which look nicer, from my point of view. The last one doesn't require `eqparbox`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{eqparbox}
    \newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

    \begin{document}

     \begin{align*}
      \eqmathbox{\mathscr{A}(B,C)\times\mathscr{A}(A,B)} & \longrightarrow \eqmathbox[R]{\mathscr{A}(A,C)}\;,\\
      \eqmathbox{(g,f)} & \longmapsto \eqmathbox[R]{g\circ f}\;,
     \end{align*}

     \begin{align*}
\mathscr{A}(B,C)\times \eqmathbox[L]{\mathscr{A}(A,B)} & \longrightarrow \eqmathbox[R]{\mathscr{A}(A,C)}\;,\\
      \eqmathbox[L]{(g,f)} & \longmapsto \eqmathbox[R]{g\circ f}\;,
     \end{align*}


     \begin{align*}
     \mathscr{A}(B,C)\times\mathscr{A}(A,B) & \longrightarrow \mathscr{A} (A,C)\;,\\
      (g,f) & \longmapsto g\circ f\;,
     \end{align*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]