# How do I write this style of functions?

Tags: math-mode, transformation

How do you thing I could write this type of function in Latex? I don't know how to make functions like in the picture.

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Simply  with the amsmath `align*` environment.

Comment: [Function definition with `align*` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473200/function-definition-diagram).

Comment: I'd be inclined to look at `array`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have your "function" using `alignat*` enviroment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
&f: \qquad &  \mathbb{R}^3 \quad& \longrightarrow \quad \mathbb{R}^3 &&  \\
&&  (x,y,z) & \longmapsto &  \mkern-25mu(2x-z, -x+y+z, z)&
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]